# Javascript condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, if-statement

i have a problem. I try to show up a div when the visibility class is visible. My code isn't working.Please help me fix this.

CSS:

```
#nor1 {position:absolute;top:100px;left:100px;z-index:2;}
#var1 {position:absolute;top:100px;left:100px;z-index:7; visibility:hidden;}
#corect {position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;z-index:9;}
```

Javascript:

```
$('#box').click(function () {
    $("#var1").css('visibility', 'visible');
});
$('#nor1').click(function () {
    if ($('#var1').css("visibility") == 'visible') {
        $('#corect').delay(500).fadeIn('slow');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works fine for me. Ensure your ID's are correct (jQuery is referencing the correct HTML element):

**jQuery:**

```
$('#nor1').click(function(){
if (($('#var1').css("visibility") == 'visible') && ($('#var2').css("visibility")) == 'visible') {
    $('#correct').delay(500).fadeIn('slow');
}});
```

**HTML:**

```
<input id="nor1" type="button" />

<div id="var1" style="visibility: visible">

</div>

<div id="correct" style="display:none">
    rtretert
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#correct {
    background-color: red;
    width:400px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/CwShT/1/

For clarity:

```
$('#nor1').click(function(){
    var1 = $('#var1').css("visibility");
    var2 = $('#var2').css("visibility");

    if ((var1 == 'visible') && (var2 == 'visible'))  {
       $('#correct').delay(500).fadeIn('slow');
    }
});
```

Comment: And if i want to put another conditions for the same div , how will work ? Like $('#nor1').click(function () {
        if ($('#var1').css("visibility") == 'visible');
    ($('#var2').css("visibility") == 'visible');{
        $('#corect').delay(1500).fadeIn('fast');}
});   I mean "corect" will show up only when var1 AND var2 are visible. Thanks

Comment: it's says there is an error in this syntax : if (var1 == 'visible') && (var2 == 'visible') . how i fix it ?

Comment: @LuicanAdrian if ((var1 == 'visible') && (var2 == 'visible'))

Comment: Thank you for the answers but it seems now it's doesn't work.I click on nor1 , they show ( var1 and var2)  but "corect" doesn't.

Comment: @LuicanAdrian - okay good. If it helped please upvote and mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think you got mixed up with your css

http://jsfiddle.net/hz9nU/2/

```
#corect {display: none;}
```

Apart from that it seems to work

Comment: And if i want to put another conditions for the same div , how will work ? Like $('#nor1').click(function () {
        if ($('#var1').css("visibility") == 'visible');
    ($('#var2').css("visibility") == 'visible');{
        $('#corect').delay(1500).fadeIn('fast');}
});   I mean "corect" will show up only when var1 AND var2 are visible. Thanks